# Как добавить картинку в homeButton в ToolBar'e

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Как можно добавить в ToolBar imageView таким образом, чтобы он располагался рядом с кнопкой back? Вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

это логотип, который можно проставлять динамично, см. http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/04/android-lollipop-toolbar-example.html

```
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```